# Melt logical matrix to long format

Tags: r

I wish to melt a logical matrix of matches of row and column names to long format.

```
#Toy input
matrix(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), nrow=2, dimnames=list(c("a","b"), c("x","y","z")))
     x     y     z
a TRUE FALSE FALSE
b TRUE  TRUE FALSE

#Desired output
  R C
1 a x
2 b x
3 b y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the matrix is called `mat`, you can use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` to get row and column number of `TRUE` values. Use that to index `rownames` and `colnames`.

```
mat1 <- which(mat, arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(R = rownames(mat)[mat1[, 1]], C = colnames(mat)[mat1[, 2]])

#  R C
#1 a x
#2 b x
#3 b y
```

Answer (score 1):

More obfuscated then above but in a single expression:

```
# Split-Apply-Combine:
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)), function(i){
  transform(data.frame(R = row.names(mat)[mat[,i, drop = TRUE]]),
             C = rep(dimnames(mat)[[2]][i], length(R)))
    }
  )
)

# OR Reshape (base):
subset(
  reshape(
    transform(mat, R = row.names(mat)),
    varying = colnames(mat),
    idvar = "R",
    v.names = "keep",
    timevar = "C",
    times = colnames(mat),
    direction = "long",
    new.row.names = seq_len(ncol(mat) * nrow(mat))
  ),
  keep,
  select = -keep
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is `x` then you can use couple of `dplyr` functions to get this.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)    
x %>% melt() %>% filter(value) %>% select(Var1, Var2)
```